# How to disconnect a device connected via adb

Tags: android, terminal, adb, platform-tools

I'm using the following `Terminal` commands to connect to an Android TV box I'm developing on:

```
cd /Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

./adb connect [my.device.ip.address]:5555
```

And it's working just fine. But when I'm attempting to disconnect from the device using the following command:

```
./adb disconnect [my.device.ip.address]:5555
```

I get the following response:

```
disconnected [my.device.ip.address]:5555
```

But in fact, I'm still connected to it. This is super strange as I'm using this command for a long time now and I never had any issues disconnecting from a device.
The only new thing in my setup, is a new version of Android Studio (version 3.5.2).

Anybody knows what changed and how can I disconnect from my device now?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to kill connection 100% use

```
adb kill-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

`adb disconnect`

and it will disconnect all devices connected via TCP. No need to specify the IP address if you're using just one device.

If it still reconnects instantly then you might have an app/script running in the background that automatically reconnects to adb.

Comment: how can i disconnect specific device if i have connected multiple devices?,
can `adb disconnect IP address` work?

Comment: @VivekThummar Yes, just `adb disconnect IP address:port`

Comment: Thank you very much,i just forgot about `port`